# Script calls in head: Attribute order best practices?

Tags: javascript, attributes, semantics

It ultimately doesn't affect the output, but I've always wondered if there is an official 'best practice' for script calls with regard to the ORDER of attributes. And, is it different for CSS versus JS calls?

For example this:

src="/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"

or this:

type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="/js/jquery.js"

or ??

Answer (score 2):

Attribute order is entirely irrelevant. There are no established best practises for them.

That said, the `language` attribute was deprecated (almost 2 decades ago!) by HTML 4 and the `type` attribute was made optional for JavaScript scripts by HTML 5. Best practise is to omit them entirely.